# ffmpeg: explicitly tag h.264 as bt.601, rather than leaving unspecified?

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, colorspace, metadata

I want to tag video as explicitly bt.601, rather than "unspecified".  I know players typically choose bt.601 as the default for videos less than 1280 pixels wide, but I want to make it explicit that bt.601 is the correct colour matrix for a video.

The sticking point is that there is no `bt601` option for ffmpeg or libx264, only bt709 and some others.

I have some videos that were downscaled from HD, and are still in bt.709, but aren't tagged properly.  So when I watch a video, I sometimes have to [manually toggle my player to bt.709](https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv/issues/1804#issuecomment-92411790).  Tagging explicitly as bt.601 will communicate to future viewers (e.g. myself) that it's definitely bt.601, and not a mis-tagged bt.709 video, when I look at it with `mediainfo`.

Another use-case for this would be if you upscaled a bt.601 video to 1280 or higher without doing a colormatrix conversion (using `-vf colormatrix`), players would incorrectly assume bt.709 if you left the color information unspecified.

FFMpeg's `colormatrix` video filter does support `bt601` as an input or output color matrix, but doesn't also set tags.  (Since it doesn't have the side-effect of setting ffmpeg's color options, it refuses to even operate with src and dest the same, like `-vf colormatrix=bt601:bt601`.)

---

```
ffmpg in  -color_primaries bt709 -color_trc bt709 -colorspace bt709  out
```

will tag the output video as using bt.709 for yuv<->rgb.  The tags end up inside the video bitstream itself, not just in the container (since this is seems to be a codec-specific thing, not a container thing, for mp4 and mkv containers at least).

e.g. `mediainfo` output:

```
Complete name             : out.mkv
...
Writing application                      : Lavf57.14.100
Writing library                          : Lavf57.14.100


Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
...
Writing library                          : x264 core 148 r2638+4 afcf21c
Encoding settings                        : cabac=1 / ref=8 / ...
Language                                 : English
Default                                  : Yes
Forced                                   : No
Color primaries                          : BT.709
Transfer characteristics                 : BT.709
Matrix coefficients                      : BT.709
```

---

So bt.709 is easy to tag.  The problem is, I don't see bt.601 anywhere.  Is one of other names an alias for it, or is there really no way to specify it explicitly?

```
x264 --fullhelp output:

  --colorprim <string>    Specify color primaries ["undef"]
                              - undef, bt709, bt470m, bt470bg, smpte170m,
                                smpte240m, film, bt2020
  --transfer <string>     Specify transfer characteristics ["undef"]
                              - undef, bt709, bt470m, bt470bg, smpte170m,
                                smpte240m, linear, log100, log316,
                                iec61966-2-4, bt1361e, iec61966-2-1,
                                bt2020-10, bt2020-12
  --colormatrix <string>  Specify color matrix setting ["???"]
                              - undef, bt709, fcc, bt470bg, smpte170m,
                                smpte240m, GBR, YCgCo, bt2020nc, bt2020c
```

`ffmpeg -h full`  shows the same set of options for its color options, which ffmpeg's `-c:v libx264` video codec passes on to x264.  Is any of these an alias for bt.601, or have a numerically equivalent colour matrix?

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Did you figure out the command line to use to get h264 HD footage tagged with BT.601?

Comment: @Casper: yes, I accepted Mulvya's answer because it was plenty of info to look up the right options.  I made an edit to include the right options explicitly (e.g. NTSC is `-color_primaries smpte170m -color_trc smpte170m -colorspace smpte170m`).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

PAL and NTSC have different color primaries, so

NTSC = SMPTE 170M = BT 601 525

PAL = BT 470 BG = BT 601 625

See the rows for value 5 & 6 on the table on page 387 of the active H.264 [standard](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-H.264-201402-I/en).

---

So the right args for ffmpeg are:

NTSC:

```
# NTSC
ffmpeg -i input  \
 -colorspace smpte170m -color_primaries smpte170m -color_trc smpte170m

mediainfo:
Color primaries                          : BT.601 NTSC
Transfer characteristics                 : BT.601
Matrix coefficients                      : BT.601
```

PAL:

`-color_trc` doesn't accept `bt470bg`, but `ffmpeg -h full` shows that `gamma28` means "BT.470 BG" for that option.

```
# PAL
ffmpeg -i input  \
 -colorspace bt470bg -color_primaries bt470bg -color_trc gamma28

mediainfo:
Color primaries                          : BT.601 PAL
Transfer characteristics                 : BT.470 System B, BT.470 System G
Matrix coefficients                      : BT.601
```

`-colorspace` is the most important option; the others don't make a visible difference for software players like `mpv` on Linux.

Comment: Ah of course.  I was even looking at the bt601 wikipedia page, and didn't clue in from the table having two rows.  Derp.

Comment: For those looking to do this same setting with HandBrake, under the Video tab, inside the Extra Options edit box, enter this string: "colorprim=smpte170m:transfer=smpte170m:colormatrix=smpte170m"